# disable click function for animation sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a sequence of images to create an animation. this works by using the coding below, however I am having the common problem of multiple clicks messing up the animation as it starts a new one.

I need to be able to disable the click while the animation is running, or a similar effect. it can either disable the click until the animation is finished, or reset the animation to start again and clear the currently running sequence.

I currently have the following code:

```
$(".startbutton").click( function() {
$(this).clearQueue( function() {

$(this).find("ul li:nth-child(1)").delay(124).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0).delay(1860).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 0);
$(this).find("ul li:nth-child(2)").delay(124).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 0).delay(125).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0);
$(this).find("ul li:nth-child(3)").delay(248).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 0).delay(125).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0);
$(this).find("ul li:nth-child(4)").delay(372).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 0).delay(125).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0);
$(this).find("ul li:nth-child(5)").delay(496).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 0).delay(125).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0);
$(this).find("ul li:nth-child(6)").delay(620).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 0).delay(125).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0);
$(this).find("ul li:nth-child(7)").delay(744).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 0).delay(125).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0);
$(this).find("ul li:nth-child(8)").delay(868).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 0).delay(125).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0);
$(this).find("ul li:nth-child(9)").delay(992).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 0).delay(125).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0);
$(this).find("ul li:nth-child(10)").delay(1116).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 0).delay(125).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0);
$(this).find("ul li:nth-child(11)").delay(1240).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 0).delay(125).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0);
$(this).find("ul li:nth-child(12)").delay(1364).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 0).delay(125).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0);
$(this).find("ul li:nth-child(13)").delay(1488).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 0).delay(125).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0);
$(this).find("ul li:nth-child(14)").delay(1612).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 0).delay(125).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0);
$(this).find("ul li:nth-child(15)").delay(1736).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 0).delay(125).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0);
$(this).find("ul li:nth-child(16)").delay(1860).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 0).delay(125).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0);
$(this).find("ul li:nth-child(17)").animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0).delay(1984).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 0);

 });
});
```

the `.clearQueue` I inserted works in that the animation can no longer be clicked multiple times and mess it up. however, once the animation sequence has finished, the animation can no longer be clicked and does not run for a second time.

I'm guessing I need to 'clear' the 'clearQueue' or something similar.

If anyone has any suggestions it would be appreciated. I have tried using the ':animated' solution that people have suggested in other similar posts which seemed a sensible solution, but it has not solved the problem so far.

Comment: [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). *Use it*.

Comment: I'm wondering about this bit: "animation can no longer be clicked". Does this mean clicking on the start button, or the actual animated elements (`ul li`)?

Comment: below is a test page with what I am trying to do, and how I have it working currently with the script I provided above. Hopefully will help.

Comment: http://trainingandfitnessblog.com/index.php?q=test1

Comment: Wow, that's pretty weird. Clicking outside `.ArticulartionClick` actually triggers the animation...

Comment: Updated my answer according to the provided example page with working JSFiddle.

Comment: there was a spelling error for the width specification, so I'm guessing it just defaulted with width to the rest of the page. is as normal now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since OP provided the example code, I will rework this answer accordingly.

Here is the working version:

http://jsfiddle.net/qZGMW/

First, use the flag as per my original suggestion:

```
var started = false;
$(selector).click(function() {
    if (started) { return; }
    started = true;
    $(this).stop(); // Do not use clearQueue
    // Do animation normally
    $(lastOne).animate(param, param, function() { started = false; });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried a a few different flags in this way but none have worked for some reason. tried yours also but didn't solve the problem either. I'm not really sure why. Will play around a bit more though.

Answer (score 1):

General code advice: there is a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) for repeated actions of the same form. As you see below, it makes for much shorter, cleaner code. Regarding your topic, [`.clearQueue`](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue) doesn't take a call-back function as a parameter. Just invoke it before you start animating. [`.stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop) may also be useful, you can experiment with the effects and see what you like.

```
$(".startbutton").click( function() {
    // $(this).clearQueue();  <- Correct usage, but unnecessary with .stop()
    $(this).stop(true, true);

    var $lis = $(this).find("ul li");
    $lis.stop(true, true);

    $lis.filter(":nth-child(1)")//.delay(124) <- Unnecessary delay here?
        .animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0).delay(1860).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 0);

    for ( var i=1; i< 16; i++ ) {
        $lis.filter(":nth-child(" + i+1 + ")")
            .delay( i * 124)
            .animate( {opacity: 1.0}, 0 )
            .delay( 125 )
            .animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0);
    }

    $lis.filter(":nth-child(17)")
        .animate({opacity: 0.0}, 0).delay(1984).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 0);
});​
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried both .clearQueue and .Stop, but neither have any effecton the animation unless I use the .clearQueue(function in the way I have above. only then will it stop multiple clicks from executing the code, while the animation is running, but also stops further clicks once it has stopped.

Comment: As for the loop code, I can't get this to execute at all at the moment. I agree that it is a tidier construct but as I only have 17 images and the animation is short, specifying individually as I have done is adequate for me, if I can get it to work. for longer ones a more concise code would be useful I shall play around with what you have given to see if i can get it to work. just as a note, the delay on the (1) is needed as it is actually the (17) that is animated first. I added some 'click' text later on which is the reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this query API](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to prevent the default action happening.

Just try this code snippet below..

```
$(".startbutton").click( function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).clearQueue( function() {
   your code continues...
```

Comment: No downvote, but I don't think it's relevant in this case. Is it?

Comment: @bvukelic Sorry about that I first look I thought that he trying to prevent the default click action.. now I see this is about multiple click actions..

Comment: No need to apologize. Just sayin'. :)